# Is there a better way to write this top down car mdoel

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-development, topdown

I Am writing a top down car drift game, where i want to make the car move in a circle and user controls the radius of the circle with the steering, basically straight steering is a straight line and turned left is a small circle to the left of the car which it will follow. as the car turns more (either side) i try to make the cars front turn more and more towards the centre, as if its drifting.

Am using unity and this is how i though i should design the model.

1. This is for a mobile game. so i have written a steering controller for the car, to control its left and right, the speed is constant.
2. There are two rigid bodies.

[image: car_fig_0]

3. The front white coloured box and the big grey coloured box both are rigid bodies. connected with a hinge joint.
4. The front box on every frame rotate a certain amount of degrees on it own z axis and moves a little forward. Thus follows a circle shape. how much is rotates  is determined my the steering.
5. I Can make both the bodies kinematic and make sure they follow a circle shape and move that way, but i also want appropriate behaviour during collisions, In the final plan there can be all kinds of collisions. So i made them kinematic and added velocities using add force methods. On it's own the front box is perfect, It rotates in circle as i change the steering the circle gets bigger everything is fine, But when i add the Other chassis box, the forces are all messed up. centrifugal forces, and the inertia messes everything.
6. Basically i need the car to drift is perfect circles and user should be able to control the radius of the circle. What is the best way to model this.

Here is the code for both the rigid bodies.

1. the front box code. This is just the fixed update method. Please ignore the controls related code. It'e unnecessary so i left it out.

   ```
   {
   //-------------------------
   // I N I T.
   //-------------------------

   current_steering_angle = controls_i.ToSignedRotation(controls_i.getSteeringAngle());
   current_steering_angle = (current_steering_angle < 0) ? (current_steering_angle + 90): current_steering_angle;
   current_steering_angle -= 45;

   //-------------------------
   // S P E E D.
   //-------------------------

   current_speed = Utils.curve_map_linear(0, 45, min_speed, max_speed, Mathf.Abs(current_steering_angle), -1);
   _rigid_body.AddRelativeForce(acceleration * Vector3.up);
   velocity = transform.InverseTransformVector(_rigid_body.velocity);
   if(velocity.y > current_speed){
       velocity.y = current_speed;
   }
   // to prevent reverse movement due to centrifugal force.
   velocity.x = 0;

   //-------------------------
   // R O T A T I O N.
   //-------------------------

   current_radius = Mathf.Sign(current_steering_angle) * Utils.exp_range_3(0, 45, min_radius, max_radius, Mathf.Abs(current_steering_angle), steering_tension, -1);
   current_rot_rate = (velocity.y / (2 * Mathf.PI * current_radius)) * 360;
   Vector3 angle = transform.localEulerAngles;
   angle.z += (current_rot_rate * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
   transform.localEulerAngles = angle;

   //-------------------------
   // A P P L Y.
   //-------------------------
   _rigid_body.velocity = transform.TransformVector(velocity); 

   }
   ```

The Utils.exp_linear and exp_range functions are just range to range mappers with some tension, to control the sensitivity of the steering on the controls.

2. Code for the chassis.

   ```
   {

   //-------------------------
   // I N I T.
   //-------------------------

   current_steering_angle = controls_i.ToSignedRotation(controls_i.getSteeringAngle());
   current_steering_angle = (current_steering_angle < 0) ? (current_steering_angle + 90): current_steering_angle;
   current_steering_angle = current_steering_angle - 45;
   current_steering_angle = ((float)((int)(current_steering_angle * Mathf.Pow(10, 5))))/Mathf.Pow(10,5);

   //-------------------------
   // R O T A T I O N.
   //-------------------------

   current_angle = front_transform.eulerAngles.z - _rigid_body.transform.eulerAngles.z;

   current_angle = (Mathf.Abs(current_angle) > 180) ? ((Mathf.Abs(current_angle) - 360) * Mathf.Sign(current_angle)) : current_angle;

   current_angle += Mathf.Sign(current_steering_angle) * Utils.curve_map_linear(0, 45, min_angle, max_angle, Mathf.Abs(current_steering_angle), 1);

   _rigid_body.transform.RotateAround(front_transform.position, Vector3.forward, current_angle);

   //-------------------------
   // S P E E D.
   //-------------------------

   Vector3 velocity = _rigid_body.transform.InverseTransformVector(_rigid_body.velocity);
   if (velocity.y < 0){
       velocity.y = 0;
   }
   _rigid_body.velocity = _rigid_body.transform.TransformVector(velocity);

   }
   ```

I would like to know how to actually implement something like this in unity. I am new to this unity stuff. I looked all over and there was a lot of stuff for 3d cars but not much on top down ones. Appreciate any kind of feedback.

Comment: I think this would be a better fit for Code Review SE.

Comment: I did think abt that. But because am not looking for just  another way to implement this, as the current code doesn't do what i want. Am looking for a solution. It's not just a review.

Comment: If it doesn't do what you want, you need to explain what it is that isn't what you want. You've explained your approach and supplied code, but I can't figure out what your problem is, beyond "how can I do this better?" which is what Code Review does.

Comment: I did ask what i want in point no 6. The current model is flaky so thats why am asking wat is a better way.

Comment: Since you want to make the most of dynamic collisions, it would probably be best if you made them non kinematic. Can you be more descriptive about the problems you have when they're non kinematic and the scene hierarchy of the car looks like?

Comment: When they are not kinematic. The centrifugal force during rotation is messing with circle shape. And there is one more thing am doing. That is rotating the chassis around the front box to change the car orientation and to get side way drift look. The angle between the cars normal and the chassis is also determined by how much the steering is turned. So if i turn the steering too fast, the chassis turns fast and inertia build in the chassis and the car juat shoots everywhere

Comment: If you want to handle collisions in a realistic way, you'll want to avoid setting velocity directly as much as possible. Try using only `AddForce`. [This answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/113203/121653) on the gamedev stackexchange explains it further.

Comment: Yeah so i am using addrelatuveforce. All velocity additons are due by add force . Only medlling with velocity to cap the speed and to prevent the car from going reverse in case of that centrifugal force but that isnt working.

Comment: You shouldn't set front tires (white bar) sideways velocity to 0. When drifting, the front tires will be moving in a direction away from the direction of the turn (which is why you turn the tires to the outside of a drift, to make the turn in the same direction they are traveling, when drifting in real life). Likewise, you shouldn't set the chassis forward velocity to zero because it has to move forward when driving normally and will have to move diagonally when drifting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193796/discussion-between-ruzihm-and-adithya-sama).

Comment: So the way it is written is not the same as a car with forward speed and rotating tyres. And am not setting the chassis velocity to 0, only when its negative to remove any reverse velocitt if genrated. Doming back to thw first thing. To make the car move in well controlled circle. I am rotating the front box a certain degree every frame and making it move forward a little every frame. Which will make a cirle. There is no actual drift here. I tried lot for that but failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it non kinematic, remove the rigidbody of the front tires and make the front tires a child of the chassis.

#### Handling position:

Make a method that looks at the car's current position, how much the player is turning, and returns the tangential velocity the car needs to go to drive in the appropriate circle:

```
Vector2 GetTangentialVelocity(...) { }
```

Then, find the difference between that velocity and the current velocity of the chassis:

```
Vector2 velDiff = GetTangentialVelocity(...) - chassis_rigidbody.velocity;
```

Then, apply that difference using `AddForce` with `ForceType.VelocityChange`:

```
chassis_rigidbody.AddForce(velDiff, ForceType.VelocityChange);
```

#### Handling rotation:

Move the center of mass forward. You can do this by making the rigidbody long and put the collider at the rear of the object, or by setting `RigidBody.centerOfMass`:

```
chassis_rigidbody.centerOfMass = Vector2.up * 0.5;
```

Make a function similar to `GetTangentialVelocity` that returns the desired angular velocity, find the difference from `chassis_rigidbody.angularVelocity`, then use `AddTorque` with `ForceType.VelocityChange`:

```
Vector2 angVelDiff = GetAngularVelocity(...) - chassis_rigidbody.angularVelocity;
chassis_rigidbody.AddTorque(angVelDiff , ForceType.VelocityChange);
```

Comment: I did work. But this shatters my understanding of multiple things. Can you answer if you don't mind. (1). When i change the centerofmass will the velocity be applied at that point or at the center of the object, based on my "experiments" unity still applies velocity at the center of object not at the centerofmass, the problem is in that case there should be some torque imparted onto the body when velocity is applied? i dont see any rotation when i apply velocity. Basically i dont understand how unity behaves when center of mass is changed.

Comment: @AdithyaSama centerOfMass is just that - the center of mass, [the point on a rigidbody where if force is applied, no torque occurs.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass). Think of changing the center of mass like putting lead weights in certain parts of the rigidbody to change how it balances

Comment: Yeah. But...This is what is noticed when i changed the center of mass. the velocity was still applied at the same spot, even after changing the center of mass. Unless the velocity is applied to every part of the body. then it would make sense.

Comment: @AdithyaSama these two outcomes are the same. Dividing up a force and applying the pieces to every unit of mass is equivalent to applying the whole force only at the center of mass. Another way of stating it, if the distance between the center of mass and where the force is applied is 0, then no torque is applied.

Comment: I do understand that: ). Hopefully am not annoying you.This is what i did,You might have to visualise this a bit. I wrote some code which applies a velocity to the car such that it moves in a circle of x radius clockwise. Now i manually change the rotation of the object around z-axis (clockwise) in the transform obj which makes it rotate around its centre(not centreOfMass). Now, There was no change in the cars movement. it rotated and kept circling, Now the centre of mass which i set is revolving at a radius less than x. I didn't change the radius, the velocity being applied didn't change.

Comment: @AdithyaSama I think it's because for the rigidbody there is no angular velocity, no torque (you can verify this by looking at `chassis_rigidbody.angularVelocity`
) so it doesn't matter where the center of mass is.  Basically, imagine a pencil going around in a circle without changing rotation. Every point on the pencil is traveling in the same size of circle, just different locations. But if you change the rotation of the pencil for just a second, during that moment only the pivot point you rotated around is going in the same circle. everything else is now going in smaller or larger circles.

Comment: It might be best to ask this in a new question if I missed something or didn't make sense :)

Comment: Agreed. Will make a new question.